# Filters in line and stacked column chart instead of legend

Tags: powerbi

I have a table in Excel file where the dates are in column A (15 dates: e.g Jul 20) and column B represents the values (in $) for company 1, column C the values (in $) for company 2, etc. (13 companies) and the last column (14th) is booked for cumulative values for all companies. I created a line (cumulative values) and stacked column chart (companies) and it is not visible in legend field (13 companies). I wanted to create the filter (using Slicer) to do something similar to check boxes in Excel and filter e.g. company 5, company 2 but it doesn't work in Power BI...it shows e.g. the company 1 and I can filter the values there... or dates.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're having trouble because your table design is a bit off. you need to unpivot it so that it looks like this (Date, Company, Dollar Value). Then your Total Value measure is

SUM('table'[Dollar Value])

and your cumulative value for a company is something like

CALCULATE([Total dollar value],FILTER(ALL(ValuefactTable),ValuefactTable[Date]<=MAX(ValueFactTable[Date])))

If you go into PowerQuery, you can (1) remove the accumulated value column (you can create a measure to do that), and then (2) select the date column, and then select Unpivot Other Columns from the PowerQuery menu. you should end up with (Company, Date, Value). Then you just create your measures and off you go.

Comment: thanks for your answer - I calculated my cumulative vales in Excel and after I copied the cells without formulas. Even when I deleted the cumulative column - I had a problem to create a visualizations for each company (by 100% Stacked column chart + Slicer).

Comment: Most of the time, the reason it's hard to create a measure is because the data table is structured incorrectly. Did you unpivot the data and try it? PowerQuery is your best friend for a job like this.